# Query multiple child item from multiple parent in multi select dropdown

Tags: php, select, multiple-select

I have problem showing the multiple city/town from selected multiple provinces.
What i have code right now, is just to show all regions, provinces and cities/towns
here's how it looks:http://screencast.com/t/VsGUZfQcBF
code:
http://pastebin.com/0HmmT35m

Answer (score 0):

You have to mix javascript and php if you want to dynamically show cities from the selected province / Region

- Retrieve the values of the selected option and then post the array with javascript to php and use the "in" statement in your select sql query

First you have to only populate the region field and when region are selected you fire javascript to post the selected regions and then populate the province with the result returned ( same with province and city )

Example for regions :

Javascript :

```
// post the value to php
var region = $('#region').val();
$.ajax({
url: 'retrieve_province.php',
data: region, 
dataType: 'json', 
success: function(json) {
 $.each(json, function(index, value) { 
 $('#province').append('<option value="'+ value+'">'+ value +'</option>');
});

}
});
```

PHP : (retrieve_province.php )

```
<?php

// --- PDO Connexion to database  
try {  
$db1 = new PDO('mysql:dbname=dbname;host=localhost', 'user', 'password');
} catch (PDOException $ex) {  
echo 'Connection failed: ' . $ex->getMessage();  
}  

// Explode the array to get the right mysql syntax
if(isset($_GET['region'])) {
$type = $_GET['region'];
$datasregion ='';

foreach($type as $val) {
  $datasregion .= "'".$val."',";
}

$datasregion = "(".substr($datasregion,0,-1).")";
}

// Execute the query
$sql_province="SELECT * FROM tbl_province where region in $datasregion ORDER   BY name ASC";
 $results = $db1->query($sql_province) or die(print_r($db1->errorInfo()));

// results
while($donnees = $results->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {

    $json[$donnees['pt_id']][] = utf8_encode($donnees['name']);
}

// send results to javascript
echo json_encode($json);


?>
```

Then you had to do the same thing for province / city

Comment: can you show me sample code? sorry about this, just a beginner in php